# financial year array between start date and end date php

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter, phppgadmin

I would like to do something of this sort in php (codeigniter), when the enter start date and end date, I would like to echo all financial years between those dates.
Financial year starts from 01-04-2001 to 31-03-2002 (April to March)

Eg:

```
public function getfinancialyears(){
      
        $startdate = $this->input->post('Date1'); //13-06-2008 *data from user input in controller
        $enddate = $this->input->post('Date2'); //27-01-2020 *data from user input in controller

}
```

Required Output :
fy = {2008-2009, 2009-2010, 2010-2011,......2019-2020};

*Want a logc that could show output of all financial years between these dates in array so that i can use fy array in loop to get further data accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next simple code as solution:

```
<?php
function getfinancialyears($startdate, $enddate){
    $startYear = date('Y', strtotime($startdate));
    $endYear   = date('Y', strtotime($enddate));

    $financeYears = [];
    
    while($startYear < $endYear ) {
        array_push($financeYears, $startYear . "-" . (++$startYear));
    }
    
    return $financeYears;
}
```

You also can test this code at [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=e6adfc9ac7a76fd533ef3948fffaa9fd&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Tried this with some modification and it works for me. Thanks alot !